# How to share connection_id between 2 queries?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to execute two SQL statements together because `connection_id()` in the first statement will be used in the Mysql view `wp_statistics_benchmarks`.

Without the `connection_id()`, the `wp_statistics_benchmarks` is an empty view. The following SQL works fine and get results:

```
replace into wp_params (`view_name` , `param1_val`, `connection_id`) 
                values ('benchmarks', 484         , connection_id())
;

select * from wp_statistic_benchmarks;
```

But, to work with wordpress, the following code doesn't work:

```
$mysqli  = new mysqli(.....);

$results = $this->_wpdb->query("
     replace into wp_params (`view_name`, `param1_val`, `connection_id`) 
                values ('benchmarks', $connected_from, $mysqli->thread_id);

     select * FROM `wp_statistic_benchmarks`;"
);
```

How can I convert these two mysql codes into Wordpress wpdb queries?

Comment: can´t you use the mysqli->multi_query function? do you actually must use wpdb?

Comment: If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22278368/1446005) didn't address your problem, then you need to show us the definition for `wp_statistic_benchmarks`, because indeed you seem to be confused as to what the problem really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements (and I do not know wordpress), you are inserting a row to wp_params with a column called connection_id. I would assume that this value will be unique on the table. I would be tempted to add an integer autoincrement id field to the table and then get the value of that (last insert id). Then use this id in a WHERE clause when selecting from the view.

Answer (score 4):

Use the wpdb object twice.

```
$this->_wpdb->query('replace into ...'); 
$rows = $this->_wpdb->get_results('select ...')
```

---

Let me put it another way, **select * from wp_stat ...** and **replace into wp_params ...** from your original "mysql codes" are separate statements without any relation to each other.

You *think* that you need to run them in sequence, whereas in fact you can have a cup of coffee or even travel around the earth in between those replace into and select statements and they would still do the same thing. If that is not the case, then your question lacks information necessary to provide a good answer because wp_params is not a standard table in wordpress and neither is *the view*. I don't think you understand your problem.

Besides, running them as I suggest is **equivalent** with your "mysql codes". Moreover, $wpdb->query returns the number of affected rows or false, so you will *never* be able to run a select statement with $wpdb->query() to retrieve a set of tuples.

Comment: this way, the value of connection_id for the two queries are different. I need them the same.

Comment: Look at your question. *replace ...;* **select * from wp_statistic_benchmarks**; - The second query is not using connection_id() in any way.

Comment: the view is created by join a table with the connection_id

Comment: Your replies indicate that you are completely confused about the problem and are looking for someone to solve your problem rather than understanding what's wrong. [Write that down in your copy book now](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dzvz1j3h4Xk#t=85)

Comment: this is the place where the wp_params come from, the connection_id is a filter for the View. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/05/19/a-workaround-for-the-performance-problems-of-temptable-views/

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convert these two mysql codes into Wordpress wpdb queries?

You can't. That's because you're using `wpdb` and it only supports *one* query per `->query()` call. However, if you're using Mysqli with `wpdb`, you *can* use the `multi_query()` method of it *with* `wpdb`. Here is how:

To use multiple queries, you need to ensure that `wpdb` uses Mysqli (e.g. define the `USE_EXT_MYSQL` constant as  `FALSE` in your Wordpress config).

Then you can obtain the `mysqli` instance from the wpdb object, either with reflection or a helper class/module:

```
abstract class wpdb_dbh extends wpdb
{
    static function from(wpdb $wpdb) {
        return $wpdb->dbh;
    }
}
```

Mysqli is then available without creating a new instance:

```
$mysqli = wpdb_dbh::from($this->_wpdb);
```

As this is a valid `Mysqli` instance you can run [multi query](https://php.net/mysqli.multi-query).

But just obtaining the same Mysqli instance as `wpdb` uses it probably the most important thing here as otherwise your open an additional connection with `new mysqli(...)` which you need to prevent.

Additionally take care that [`$mysqli->thread_id`](http://php.net/mysqli.thread-id) is a fitting replacement to [`connection_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) following the same formatting/encoding. You should be able to use `connection_id()` directly anyway, so I actually see not much reason to access the `thread_id` member, but it's perhaps only because you tried some alternatives and I'm just over-cautious.

Answer (score 2):

The ';' query delimiter is purely an SQL shell convenience and is not a part of the MySQL dialect so you're correct that your code doesn't work.

Here's the actual replacement code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(.....);
$this->_wpdb->query(
     "replace into wp_params
    (`view_name`, `param1_val`, `connection_id`) 
    values ('benchmarks', $connected_from, $mysqli->thread_id)");
$results = $this->_wpdb->query("select * FROM `wp_statistic_benchmarks`");
```

This is the same as Ярослав's answer above.

## Update:

If your code is still not working you might have to [enable persistent connections](http://wordpressapi.com/persistent-database-connection-wordpress/) in Wordpress.

## Update 2:

There was a missing space between in the second query's **select** statement and the ***** shorthand all columns selector.  Interestingly this may or may not cause an issue for you, it doesn't seem to bother my MySQL 5.5 command line shell.